# What obligations does Russia have towards the cleanup /maintenance of Chernobyl?

Tags: russian-federation, international-law, ukraine, succession, soviet-union

As a successor state of the USSR, what legal responsibilities does the Russian Federation have towards aiding the cleanup of Chernobyl and the Chernobyl Exclusion Zone(such as rehabilitation, building the sarcophagus), which is now mostly in Belarus and Ukraine(former parts of the USSR)?

Comment: FYI, the €1.5bn New Safe Confinement has been paid by the EBRD.

Comment: Interesting thanks for pointing that out! Why did the EBRD pay for that though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No obligations at all.**

Just because soviet republics, who've re-formed to modern Ukraine and Belarus during USSR dissolution, claimed all property on their land as their own.

If some attempt of such claims would be present, there just may be a counter-act - sending a bill for all USSR property left in republic at the moment of dissolution. And we are not talking about borders and territories now.

Answer (score 0):

None, because [successor states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Succession_of_states) only have sovereignty over the territory they inherit.

> Succession of states is a concept in international relations regarding a successor state that has become a **sovereign state over a territory (and populace) that was previously under the sovereignty of another state**. The theory has its roots in 19th-century diplomacy.

As sovereign states, all 15 former Soviet Republics are successor states of the Soviet Union.